# Is it possible to modify an incoming request's header?

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I have a laravel php framework set up, I want to set some header to all incoming requests so my framework's plugin can find it in the header.

Is it possible to modify incoming request's header?

I tried this but it didn't modify the request header.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = "Bearer xxx";
echo Request::header("Authorization"); // "" (ie., it displays nothing)
```

Comment: I know that this is not good practice, but as a quick fix, I need to set authorization header to all incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

The application is not the place to deal with HTTP headers. It should be done with web server. Try [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html).

This module provides directives to control and modify HTTP request and response headers. Headers can be merged, replaced or removed. In your case

`Header set MyHeader "Authorization"`